# Qual é a finalidade do virtualenv e por que não instalar globalmente?

Tags: python

Vi que o `VirtualEnv` provê uma forma de criar diferentes ambientes para desenvolvimento de aplicações em `Python`. E, sempre que utilizamos, é necessário instalar as dependências de um projeto específico.

Por exemplo, percebo que, quando se trata de projetos como `Django` e afins, há uma recomendação forte de se utilizar esse ambiente virtual.

Porém, como estou acostumado a programar em `PHP` e nunca tive problemas em utilizar a mesma versão do PHP para  os meus projetos, comecei a me questionar se realmente é necessário ou se toda a situação seria necessário.

Porque, ao que parece, uma versão do `Python` é instalada, junto com `Pip` e `Easy install`, para cada `Virtual Env` criado. Já em PHP, podemos por exemplo, apenas utilizar as dependências necessárias num projeto, através do `Composer`, e utilizar o `PHP` que já está instalado para desenvolver, nesse caso bastando apenas se ater aos detalhes da versão utilizada.

Então, gostaria que quem tivesse experiência maior que a minha em  `Python` me explicasse:

- Quais são os pontos positivos de se utilizar o VirtualEnv?
- Existe algum caso onde não devo me preocupar em usar o VirtualEnv?
- É essencial que em todos os **tipos de projetos** eu use `VirtualEnv`, ou apenas casos conflitantes?
- Não seria melhor instalar tudo globalmente ao invés de usar `VirtualEnv`? Pois querendo ou não, é um passo a mais acrescentado no desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usando VirtualEnv você isola as dependências de um projeto das de outros, alguns exemplos onde isso salva vidas:

1. Você trabalha em vários projetos simultaneamente, e alguns utilizam versão X de uma biblioteca, enquanto outros usam a Y. Isso é bem comum, pode ser que em um projeto anterior tenha usado a versão 1.1.x da lib e em um novo esteja querendo testar a 1.9.x que tem 999 bug fixes mas que talvez tem algo que funcionava antes quebrado agora (e isso também é bem comum), nesse cenário com VirtualEnv você consegue manter os dois funcionando em paralelo.
2. Sua equipe desenvolve um software e mantêm dois repositórios, um "trunk|edge|latest" onde tudo que é novo é commitado e outro "stable" que é aquele em que a última versão 100% testada do software fica. Você na sua máquina local geralmente trabalha no "latest" mas as vezes precisa dar uma olhada no "stable", é bem provável que eventualmente você venha a atualizar bibliotecas no "latest", assim sem usar VirtualEnv você não consegue rodar os dois branches do seu software simultaneamente porque só vai conseguir ter uma versão das bibliotecas que eles dependem instalada globalmente no sistema.
3. Você tem um servidor onde hospeda vários softwares para produção. Os mais antigos podem usar versões velhas de certas bibliotecas, e você não quer ter que ficar atualizando eles, o bagulho está no ar, funciona e o cliente está feliz, porque perder tempo mexendo e arriscar quebrar? com VirtualEnv todos tem suas dependências isoladas, assim o projeto que foi feito 2 anos atrás pode continuar rodando sem problemas com a pré-histórica versão -0.0.1 da biblioteca X, e os mais novos podem usar a versão 99 sem drama.

Como você pode ver as vantagens são mais acentuadas quando se trabalha com vários softwares simultaneamente. Como exemplo da vida real eu costumo estar em >4 projetos ao mesmo tempo, todos tem que estar rodando para na minha máquina sempre, se as dependências fossem instaladas globalmente ia ser o caos completo.

Outras vantagem do virtualenv é que, como você comentou na pergunta, ele pode prover uma versão separada dos próprios binários de python, pip e easy_install. Isso te dá um nível extra de isolamento, é pouco menos útil que a separação de versões de bibliotecas mas ainda assim existem casos onde você quer usar versões desses programas que são diferentes das instaladas no seu sistema operacional, pois pode ser que elas tenham dependências de pacotes que acabariam bagunçando tudo.

No fim depende do seu contexto, se você trabalha em um projeto python por vez, termina e engaveta ele pela eternidade, não vai ter problemas instalando tudo globalmente, também se você usa apenas uma versão fixa de python em todos eles (a que está instalada em seu SO) não há motivos para criar cópias da mesma.

Comment: resposta boa, obrigado +1. No meu caso então, tenho que usar VirtualEnv. Os projetos são em PHP, mas se um dia for migrar para Python, são 10 sistemas que eu trabalho ao mesmo tempo

Comment: Na verdade, se o PHP não tem um dispositivo semelhante, isso só traz desvantagens - a quantidade de espaço em disco que os VirtualEnvs usam é negligível em relação ao tamanho dos HDs modernos - essa seria a única desvantagem.

Mesmo assim, ainda é possível instalar alguns pacotes no sistema, e outros distintos em cada virtualenv, em alguns casos - basta criar o virtualenv com a opção  `--with-sytem-packages` e pacotes como "ipython" ou "ipdb"  que não são realmente parte dos projetos podem ser compartilhados.