# Como definir Python 3 como padrão no linux?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Quando digito o comando `python`, o Ubuntu executa o Python 2.7. Porém nas novas versões do Ubuntu, o Python 3 também costuma vir instalado.

Quando eu executo `python -V`, aparece "Python 2.7.12", mas eu gostaria de usar o comando `python` para executar a versão `3.5`.

Eu bem que poderia criar um link simbólico ou coisas do tipo, mas como não sei se isso é o mais correto a se fazer, pergunto:

Existe algum jeito específico para alterar a versão padrão do comando `python`, sem fazer gambiarra ou prejudicar o funcionamento no Ubuntu?

Comment: Observação: Fiz essa pergunta, porque no caso do [PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190556/como-mudar-a-vers%C3%A3o-do-php-em-que-o-composer-%C3%A9-executado-no-linux), para fazer isso, o procedimento é um pouco diferente do que simplesmente definir um alias e tals, e fiquei com medo de dar problemas.

Comment: she-bang (assim poderia executar 'diretamente') ou virtualenv :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema criando um alias através do `~/.bashrc`.

Código

```
>> nano  ~/.bashrc
```

Coloque o seguinte código no final

```
alias python=python3
```

Alguém poderia dizer que o comando `upate-alternatives` poderia resolver isso, mas de [acordo com essa resposta](https://askubuntu.com/a/460578/395403) não é correto utilizá-lo no caso do Python.

Comment: Eu tenho receio de que haja fluxos em que o `bashrc` não seja carregado

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado talvez então a solução fosse usar alterar o link simbólico

Comment: Segundo a resposta que diz que o `update-alternatives` não é o correto, a justificativa é porque os Pythons não são intercambiáveis. Qualquer alternativa para "intercambiar", então, segundo o autor _webwurst_, estaria errada. Mas segundo o _hhlp_, você consegue conviver com versões alternativas: https://askubuntu.com/a/26518

Answer (score 2):

Cara, eu não alteraria o python default do sistema pelo simples fato de que coisas que o sistema usa e dependem do python 2, quebrariam se você alterasse.

Uma boa prática é usar ambientes virtuais, neste guia você encontra um material legal a respeito.

https://medium.com/welcome-to-the-django/guia-definitivo-para-organizar-meu-ambiente-python-a16e2479b753

Conforme mencionado nos comentários, aqui também tem mais informações sobre o uso de ambientes virtuais

[Qual é a finalidade do virtualenv e por que não instalar globalmente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126852/qual-%C3%A9-a-finalidade-do-virtualenv-e-por-que-n%C3%A3o-instalar-globalmente)

Comment: Entendi. Talvez valha a pena acrescentar isso [aqui então](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126852/qual-%C3%A9-a-finalidade-do-virtualenv-e-por-que-n%C3%A3o-instalar-globalmente), para vincular à pergunta

Comment: Ainda assim, acho que seja uma boa ideia ter a informação na resposta, para não sairmos do foco da pergunta.