# UnicodeDecodeError em "pip upgrade" e em "install pywinusb"

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pip

A minha experiência em Python não é muita, mas ainda não tinha aparecido nenhum erro deste género em qualquer instalação. Como aparecia sempre a mensagem para fazer o upgrade da versão do pip, decidi prosseguir com esta actualização, e foi aí que me apareceu este erro.

Antes já tinha instalado o pacote "pyusb" sem qualquer problema.

Tentei depois instalar o pacote "pywinusb" e tive o mesmo erro que no upgrade do pip.

Já fiz diversas pesquisas através do google, mas não encontrei nenhuma resposta que explicasse o porquê deste erro...

```
PS C:\Python27> pip --version
pip 18.1 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip (python 2.7)

PS C:\Python27> python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 318, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 283, in prepare_linked_requirement
    progress_bar=self.progress_bar
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 836, in unpack_url
    progress_bar=progress_bar
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 673, in unpack_http_url
    progress_bar)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 895, in _download_http_url
    file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 85, in join
    result_path = result_path + p_path
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

PS C:\Python27> pip install pywinusb
Collecting pywinusb
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 318, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 283, in prepare_linked_requirement
    progress_bar=self.progress_bar
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 836, in unpack_url
    progress_bar=progress_bar
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 673, in unpack_http_url
    progress_bar)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 895, in _download_http_url
    file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, filename)
  File "c:\python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 85, in join
    result_path = result_path + p_path
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

A minha questão é o que pode estar a provocar o erro: "**UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)**"?

Comment: Acerca deste erro em particular: "**UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)**", quando tentava fazer o upgrade ao pip ou ao tentar instalar qualquer pacote python, devia-se ao nome da minha pasta de utilizador. A minha pasta tinha o nome "C:/Users/Sérgio Neves", e o "é" em "Sérgio" era o problema, então modifiquei o nome da minha pasta para "C:/Users/SergioNeves", sem acentos ou espaços. Assim, já consegui instalar o pip e os pacotes python.

Answer (score 0):

Pode tentar atualizar o Python para alguma versão mais atual (tipo versão 3.7). Com o Python atualizado e configurado no `path` do Windows acredito que não terá dificuldade. Se precisar manter a versão 2.7 por algum motivo pode utilizar o [virtualenv](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126852/qual-%C3%A9-a-finalidade-do-virtualenv-e-por-que-n%C3%A3o-instalar-globalmente).